Is it possible to create a Pie chart using VF page that shows all the aggregated fields from a report
VF Page::
<apex:page controller="TestDanixController">
    <head>
        <apex:includeScript value="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="pieChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
        <script>
            // Get data from controller
            var labels = {!pieLabels};
            var dataValues = {!pieData};
            
            var data = {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    data: dataValues,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)'
                    ]
                }]
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById('pieChart').getContext('2d');
            var pieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: data
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</apex:page>

Apex Controller::
public class TestDanixController {
    // Salesforce base URL
    private static final String SALESFORCE_BASE_URL = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm();

    public List<String> getPieLabels() {
        List<String> labels = new List<String>();
        String reportId = '00OAD000002T5xd2AC'; // Replace with your report ID

        if (String.isNotBlank(reportId)) {
            // Make REST API call to get report data
            String reportInstanceUrl = getReportInstanceUrl(reportId);
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(reportInstanceUrl);
            req.setMethod('GET');
            // Add authentication headers using a named credential
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            // Add any other required headers

            HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);

            // Process the response and extract labels
            if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
                List<Map<String, Object>> reportData = (List<Map<String, Object>>) jsonResponse.get('factMap');
                for (Map<String, Object> entry : reportData) {
                    labels.add((String) entry.get('label'));
                }
            }
        }

        return labels;
    }

    public List<Integer> getPieData() {
        List<Integer> dataValues = new List<Integer>();
        String reportId = '00OAD000002T5xd2AC'; // Replace with your report ID

        if (String.isNotBlank(reportId)) {
            // Make REST API call to get report data
            String reportInstanceUrl = getReportInstanceUrl(reportId);
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(reportInstanceUrl);
            req.setMethod('GET');
            // Add authentication headers using a named credential
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer {!$Credential.OAuthToken}');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            // Add any other required headers

            HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);

            // Process the response and extract data values
            if (res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
                List<Map<String, Object>> reportData = (List<Map<String, Object>>) jsonResponse.get('factMap');
                for (Map<String, Object> entry : reportData) {
                    dataValues.add((Integer) entry.get('aggregates'));
                }
            }
        }

        return dataValues;
    }

    // Method to construct the report instance URL
    private static String getReportInstanceUrl(String reportId) {
        return SALESFORCE_BASE_URL + '/services/data/v53.0/analytics/reports/' + reportId + '/instances';
    }
}

